# Extract values from a list with range of values from another to create a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list like this,

```
main_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I have another list like this,

```
sec_list = [0, 5, 10]
```

Now, I need an output dictionary like this:

```
extract_dict = {0:[1,2,3,4], 5:[6,7,8,9], 10:[11,12,13,14]}
```

My key will be for the dictionary is from `sec_list` and values are from `main_list`.

I was trying to select the range of values using `sec_list` values like this,

```
extract_dict = {}
for i in range(len(sec_list)-1):
    extract_dict[sec_list[i]] = main_list[sec_list[i]:sec_list[i+1]]
```

I got an output like this, which is not what I like,

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 5: [7, 8, 9, 11, 12]}
```

How can I achieve my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following:

```
main_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]

sec_list = [0, 5, 10]

extract_dict = {}

for i, k in enumerate(sec_list):
  if i < len(sec_list) - 1:
    p = sec_list[i + 1]
    extract_dict[k] = main_list[k - i : (k - i) + p - k - 1]
                              #[k - i : p - i - 1] <== can be simplified to
  else:
    extract_dict[k] = main_list[k - i : ]

print(extract_dict)
```

Output:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 5: [6, 7, 8, 9], 10: [11, 12, 13, 14]}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand why you used `i+4` in `...[k - i : k - i + 4]`? is it because there is increment by 4? If so, what if the increment is different numbers for different keys? Because this list won't be static and will be dynamic, so I am thinking about automating.

Comment: @user9431057 If increments change, you can subtract each element from the one after it and use that as an increment (check the edit).